# How to connect to MongoDB using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I cannot connect to MongoDB.

This is my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,format =require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', function(err, db){
  if(err){
    throw err;
  }else{
    console.log("daniel is connected");
  }
})
```

I get in the console log that I am connected when I command 'npm start', however when I go to my URL 'http://localhost:3000/api' which is the URL I set for the DB, I get an error page displaying 'localhost refused to connect.'.

Comment: could you add more code to the example? http://localhost:3000/api refers to an http endpoint, so you need to use express (or a similar framework) to handle http request and "show html pages".

Comment: Hi Daniel. How are you running mongodb? Is it running on your local machine, or in a docker container? Using the IP address of 127.0.0.1 indicates that it is on your machine, are you sure it's installed properly?

Comment: I highly suggest using mongoose instead of mongodb. In any case, try changing '127.0.0.1' to 'localhost' or access the browser by typing 'http://127.0.0.1:27017'. Believe me sometimes these things can mess up a lot! improper DNS settings can lead to these kind of issues.